# Android opengl es draw an image on texture by sending all vertices of the image

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was reading this https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive and thought that gl_patches will solve my issue but looks like it is not supported in opengl es, I want to send the vertices of the width and height of the whole image through glVertixAttribPointer, so if the image is w=10* h=20 I need it to send 200 points to the vertexShader but I don't know how to do that with the available modes of opengl es glDrawArrays function.

UPDATE:
After updating to opengl es 3.2 I am now able to find GL_PATCHES mode, my question now does it help to use GL_PATCHES to send all vertices of the image to the vertex shader? If yes, how?

why do I need to do that, it is because I want to send a float value for each pixel of the image manipulate the pixels with these values, this means that I need to send a floatBuffer to the vertexShader(then send it to the values to the fragmentShader) according to my understanding I need to send the vertices to match the number of data I need to send in this floatBuffer(I could be wrong tho)

I am using these vertices rn for the vertexShader.

```
val vertexArray = floatArrayOf(
        -width / 2f, -height / 2f,  // 0 bottom left
        +width / 2f, -height / 2f,  // 2 bottom right
        -width / 2f, +height / 2f,  // 3 top left
        +width / 2f, +height / 2f,  // 5 top right
        +width / 2f, -height / 2f,  // 2 bottom right
        -width / 2f, +height / 2f  // 3 top left
    )
val texArray = floatArrayOf(
        0.0f, 1.0f,  // 0 bottom left
        1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2 bottom right
        0.0f, 0.0f,  // 3 top left
        1.0f, 0.0f,  // 5 top right
        1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2 bottom right
        0.0f, 0.0f  // 3 top left
    )
```

THEN convert these arrays to buffers(vertexBuffer and texBuffer)

I then use glVertexAttribPointer for each with its location index as follows:

```
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc)
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray")

    // Connect vertexBuffer to "aPosition".
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        positionLoc, coordsPerVertex,
        GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer
    )
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer")



    // Enable the "aTextureCoord" vertex attribute.
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordLoc)
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray")

    // Connect texBuffer to "aTextureCoord".
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        textureCoordLoc, 2,
        GL_FLOAT, false, texStride, texBuffer
    )
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer")
```

Currently it is drawing the texture successfully but I can't do the shader processing because I can't send the buffer with the processing data for each pixel as I said above.

Comment: `GL_PATHCES` and tessellation shaders are supported in [OpenGL ES 3.2](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)

Comment: upgraded my proj to use opengl 3.2 instead and it has it indeed, it also now has the QUADS and all those lovely stuff, I will update the question

Comment: However, after your question, it is completely puzzling what you actually want to do. What have you tried to do so far? What are you struggling with? Why do you need to send 200 points to the shader? Why aren't you using texture and/or look-up texture? This seams to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: sorry I updated it again, I should use the word pixel instead of vertex I fixed that now @Rabbid76

Comment: I will update the q with my code

Comment: I was looking in a different area, I indeed have the same issue but I was asking a wrong question so I deleted it and asked this question instead after knowing extra info, what do u suggest, delete this one and reopen the other one and update it? @Rabbid76

Comment: what do u suggest? should I delete it and re-open the other one? and update the other one? @Rabbid76

Comment: I am very certain that you do not try to do something that no one has done before. I am also confident that there is a common and straightforward way to do what you want to do (without patches and tessellation). However, in order to help you, I must first find out what you want to do. This is still a great mystery to me.

Comment: Sorry for confusion I know my explanation is not great anyway. I will try again to explain in a comment what I need @Rabbid76

Comment: I need to send a buffer full of floats, each float will be used to manipulate the pixels in the fragment shader, so if the float value for example is less than .15 I will set the colour of the pixel to say C1 and if the float value is larger than .15 I will set the colour of the pixel to another certain colour lets say C2

from what I have read I need to make the vertices of the vertex shader equal to the number of the floats of the different pixels. Am I right? @Rabbid76